# How to calculate total uncertainties from this physics equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, error-propagation

I have a maths question asking the total % uncertainty in the velocity of a skidding car given by this equation provided by my teacher:

1/2 * m * v^2 = force * distance = m * g * f * d

where m = mass with an uncertainty of +/- 4%

g = 9.80665 m/s^2

f = coefficient of friction with an uncertainty of +/- 5%

d = length of skid marks +/- 3%

I simplified the equation, removing m:

v^2 = 2·g·f·d

Then I calculated total uncertainty of v^2 to be the uncertainty of f + the uncertainty of d = 5% + 3% = 8%

**Three questions:**

Am I correct in leaving out the constants 2 and g, since I am using relative uncertainties?

Should I have somehow also included the uncertainty of m, which I left out after simplifying the equation?

How would I then calculate the uncertainty of v from the uncertainty of v^2?

Comment: You need to use derivatives for this one. Partial derivatives: 2*dv=2*(dg*f*d+g*df*d+g*f*dd)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rough answer is you are right in adding the uncertainties of $f$ and $d$.  If they were both high instead of $fd$ you would have $1.05f1.03d=1.0815fd$.  We ignore the quadratic part of the uncertainty, which is the $0.0015=0.05 \cdot 0.03$.  You are also correct in dividing out the $m$ analytically and noting the resulting equation does not depend on $m$ so its uncertainty does not matter at all.

Once you have $\frac {\Delta (v^2)}{v^2}=8\%$ you can use the fact that $(1+a)^n \approx 1+an$ as long as $an \ll 1$.  This gives $\frac {\Delta v}v = \frac 12\frac {\Delta (v^2)}{v^2}=4\%$